# How to pass a member function which has variable arguments as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pointer-to-member

I want to write an adapter which can convert *non static member functions* to C-style function pointers. Here is what I got now(see the following code snippet), but the current solution is not general. I want to make `int (T::*Func)(int)` accept variable arguments.

Also it's necessary to make `CObjectT::f`  and `StoreVals::display` have the same signature.

**The final goal is Interfacing C++ member functions with C libraries.**

```
class StoreVals
{
    int val;
public:
    int display(int k) { cout << k << endl; return 0; }
};

template<class T, int (T::*Func)(int)>
class CObjectT
{
public:
    /*
     * The signagure of 'f(...)' should change by the argument of template.
     * They must be the same, but i don't know how to achieve this goal.
     */
    static int f(int i)
    { 
        T obj;
        return (obj.*Func)(i);
    }
};

void main()
{
    CObjectT<StoreVals, &StoreVals::display>::f(7);
    auto function_t = &CObjectT<StoreVals, &StoreVals::display>::f;

    // Now it's a C-style function pointer
    cout << typeid(function_t).name() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the point? You can only invoke your C-style function with the single default value of T.

Comment: @ n.m., see my updates. it's just a ugly code snippet to make me understood. int f() and display must have the same signature. Now i want to make it a general solution. the signature of f(...) should change by the argument of int (T::*Func)

Comment: Your ultimate goal may or may not be achievable. Let's concentrate at the code you have. What `CObjectT<Person,&Person::age>` does? Whose age would it return?

Comment: @n.m. um..., the argument should be set by user. the function can accept variable. we should call like this: CObjectT<Person, &Person::age)::age(25);

Comment: In your example, `StoreVals::display` doesn't use `val` in any way; it might as well be a static member, or a regular non-member function. Make it print `val`. Then try to make your example call `display` twice, on two different `StoreVals` instances initialized with different values for `val`. This should prove educational.

Comment: "I want to have something with state behave as if it had no state." That makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to dynamically change the name of a function based on a template parameter, but you can change the arguments/return type based on the template parameter. It does require some extra type information in the template declaration but it does allow what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template< typename T, T t >
class Delegate;


template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args, R ( C::*F ) ( Args... )>
class Delegate< R ( C::*)( Args... ), F > {
public:
    template< typename... Ts >
    static R invoke( Ts&&... args ) {
        C t;
        return ( t.*F )( std::forward< Ts >( args )... );
    }

};

template< typename R, typename... Args, R ( *F ) ( Args... ) >
class Delegate< R ( * ) ( Args... ), F > {
public:
    template< typename... Ts >
    static R invoke( Ts&&... args ) {
        return F( std::forward< Ts >( args )... );
    }
};

void print( int v ) {
    std::cout << "Static: " << v << std::endl;
}

class Class {

    void print( int v ) {
        std::cout << "Class: " << v << std::endl;
    }

};

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    Delegate< void ( * )( int ), &print >::invoke( 1 );
    Delegate< void ( Class::* ) ( int ), &Class::print >::invoke( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Static: 1
Class: 1
```

This does use C++11's variadic templates and Rvalue References for perfect forwarding. That is why you see the weird `std::forward< Args >( args )...` in the function calls.

This doesn't work with variadic parameter functions such as printf and the like. It might be possible but would require a lot more template black magic that I don't have time to write and test.

Comment: `static_cast<Args&&>(args)` does not perfect-forward args! This is not Universal Reference. It won't work with l-values.

Comment: @PiotrS. Fixed, but I don't much like the solution.

Comment: not sure, but I think now it can be simplified: `std::forward<Ts>(args)...`, because you still cast value to r-value reference to each of type from Args list

Comment: @PiotrS. That is correct. I had that change in my local copy but didn't change it in the example. Editing it now.

Comment: @PiotrS. I think it can be improved further using a form of std::enable_if to test whether the arguments can be converted to the required types. It might reduce the amount of cryptic error messages generated from using incorrect types.

Comment: @Smith_61 your answer is almost perfect, but i can't compile it in Visual Studio 2013. here is the compiling error:(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\template.cpp', line 22679)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>          Console.cpp(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Delegate<void (__thiscall Class::* )(int),Class::print>' being compiled

Comment: @Triumphant Visual studio is really really bad at templates. It does not comply to the standard very well. It also constantly crashes with usage of template specialization that GCC handles. I recommend if you are doing heavy template usage to use GCC such as MinGW for windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interface with C, you cannot use templates and you cannot use member functions (even static). The only way is a honest hand-written `extern "C"` function. Templates or member functions cannot have C linkage.

If you want to sacrifice portability for convenience you can do something like this:

```
#define TYPE_AND_VALUE(x) decltype(x),x

#define MemFuncTypeAdapter(x) MemFuncTypeAdapterStruct<TYPE_AND_VALUE(x)>

extern "C" 
{
    int (*cfunc)(struct A*, int);
}

template <typename MemFuncType> struct MemFuncTypes;
template <typename Class, typename Ret, typename... Args> 
struct MemFuncTypes<Ret (Class::*)(Args...)>
{
    using RetType = Ret;
    using ClassType = Class;
};

template <typename MemFuncType, MemFuncType memFunc>
struct MemFuncTypeAdapterStruct
{
    using RetType = typename MemFuncTypes<MemFuncType>::RetType;
    using ClassType = typename MemFuncTypes<MemFuncType>::ClassType;

    template <typename... Args>
    static RetType func (ClassType* c, Args... args) 
    {
        return (c->*memFunc)(args...);
    }
};

struct A
{
    A() : a(33) {};
    int a;
    int plus (int b) { return a + b; }
};

int main ()
{
    MemFuncTypeAdapter(&A::plus) aplus;
    A a;
    aplus.func(&a, 22);

    cfunc = &MemFuncTypeAdapter(&A::plus)::func; //<- C interface here

}
```

Notes.

1. The adapter has an additional `Class*` argument. See comments for an explanation of this.
2. Don't bother with perfect forwarding. You are passing C compatible types in there anyway. Which means scalars and pointers only.
3. The ugly macro is necessary to avoid repeating `typename(x), x` every time. Hopefully a future C++ standard will deal with it.
4. Parts of this can probably be found in the standard library, pointers are welcome.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c7c6bf1a7dfcff)